# Removing null objects from nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I have the following array:

```
const obj = [
    {
        "descricao": "PCS ",               
        "children": [
            null,
            {
                "name": "Son",
                "children": [
                    {        
                        "name": "Son2",               
                        "children": [],                        
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Son3",               
                        "children": [],
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
               "name": "Son4",
                "children": [
                    {        
                        "name": "Son4",               
                        "children": [],                        
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Son4",               
                        "children": [],
                    }
                ],
            },
            {
                "name": "Son",
                "children": [
                    {        
                        "name": "Son2",               
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "name": "More"                                
                                "children": [
                                    null,
                                    {
                                        ...other objects
                                    }
                                ],                                
                            }
                        ], 
                    },
                ],
            },            
        ],
    },
    {
        "name": "awesome",
        "children": [
            {                
                "children": [],             
                "ativa": true
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "name": "children",
        "children": []
    },
]
```

I want to be able to **remove** all the `null` from the childrens array, the issue right here is the nesting arrays, since I can have multiple nested arrays which contains more arrays, in which can have null elements.

I attempted a recursive function. which did not succeed:

```
function deactiveRecursive(obj) {
    if (!obj) return;
  return {
    ...obj,    
    children: obj.children.filter(child => child !== null)
  };
}

function removeRecursive() {
    return obj.filter((aprop) => {        
        return {
            ...aprop,
            chidlren: aprop["children"].filter((c) => deactiveRecursive(c))
        }
    })
}
```

I have used this logic before to attempt to remove an item with a certain id **(it works, but i wanted to erase the objects instead of having to return null or undefined)**, although I could `erase` it, since the return has to have something. This logic, is the logic that made it return null from the objects I want to remove

```
const deact = JSON.stringify(
        this.array,
        (_, nestedValue) => {
          if (nestedValue && nestedValue['_id'] === MyWanteIdToRemove._id) {
            return null
          }
          return nestedValue
        }
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can recursively change the object **in-place** and remove nulls from arrays by splicing them.

```js
const obj = [
    {
        "descricao": "PCS",
        "children": [
            null, null, null,
            {
                "name": "Son",
                "children": [
                    null, null, null,
                    {
                        "name": "Son2",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    null, null, null,
                    {
                        "name": "Son3",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    null, null, null
                ]
            },
            null, null, null,
            {
               "name": "Son4",
                "children": [
                    null, null, null,
                    {
                        "name": "Son4",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    null, null, null,
                    {
                        "name": "Son4",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    null, null, null
                ]
            },
            null, null, null,
            {
                "name": "Son",
                "children": [
                    null, null, null,
                    {
                        "name": "Son2",
                        "children": [
                            null, null, null,
                            {
                                "name": "More",
                                "children": [
                                    null, null, null,
                                    { "other": "objects..." },
                                    null, null, null
                                ]
                            },
                            null, null, null
                        ]
                    },
                    null, null, null
                ]
            },
            null, null, null
        ]
    },
    null, null, null,
    {
        "name": "awesome",
        "children": [
            null, null, null,
            {
                "children": [ null, null, null ],
                "ativa": true
            },
            null, null, null
        ]
    },
    null, null, null,
    {
        "name": "children",
        "children": [ null, null, null ]
    },
    null, null, null
];

function removeNulls (object) {
    if (typeof object == 'object' && object != null) {
        if (Array.isArray(object)) {
            for (let i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
                if (object[i] === null) {
                    object.splice(i--, 1);
                }
                else {
                    removeNulls(object[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (object.children) {
            removeNulls(object.children);
        }
    }
}

removeNulls(obj)
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thats awesome, are we able to make make a id selection like on the last example I mentioned attached to your solution?

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF Hmm... I don't think that I understand how `_id` relates to the example you provided. If you add another example that makes it clear what are you struggling with, it will certainly help.

Comment: Actually, that's great, I will try to deal with it myself